# I'm getting error while running start-dfs.sh

Tags: hadoop

I'm getting error while running start-dfs.sh

```
start-dfs.sh
16/10/02 23:10:54 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /opt/hadoop/logs/hadoop-root-namenode-Web.out
localhost: nice: /home/hadoop/hadoop/bin/hdfs: No such file or directory
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /opt/hadoop/logs/hadoop-root-datanode-Web.out
localhost: nice: /home/hadoop/hadoop/bin/hdfs: No such file or directory
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /opt/hadoop/logs/hadoop-root-secondarynamenode-Web.out
0.0.0.0: nice: /home/hadoop/hadoop/bin/hdfs: No such file or directory
16/10/02 23:11:12 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

Comment: Does file `hdfs` exist in directory `/home/hadoop/hadoop/bin/`?

Comment: yes directory     /opt/hadoop/bin/hdfs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the hadoop home env var.

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop
```

then try is anything working

```
hadoop version
```

Issues like yours depends on lack of env var.